# Insert Data into SQL Server database - Winforms

Tags: c#, sql-server, winforms, visual-studio

I am trying to insert the data once user clicks on button "druk". The connection string does not seem to be set properly as the debug stop at this point and does not go further. I have the Data Connection set and connected. I have removed and replaced username from connection string due to security reasons.

- Server: `s59.hekko.net.pl`
- Database name: `truex2_kuba`
- Database table: `barcode`

Code:

```
private void druk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection();
    con.ConnectionString = "DataSource=s59.hekko.net.pl; Initial Catalog=username; Integrated security=true";
    con.Open();

    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into [barcode]values(@class, @tree, @type, @amount, @length, @width, @square)";

    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@class", klasa.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tree", gatunek.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@type", rodzaj.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@amount", amount.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@length", length.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@width", width.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@square", textBox1.Text);

    int a = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

    if (a > 0)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Zapisane do raportu");
    }
}
```

Comment: Initial Catalog should be set to _truex2_kuba_ while the username and the password have their keys to be set, Integrated Security seems not be the correct key to use here on a remote database

Comment: Do you have any error message to share?

Comment: It only says: Exception thrown: 'System.ArgumentException' in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Keyword not supported: 'datasource'.

Comment: @Steve, what should I use instead of integrated security? Where should I enter a db password here? Thanks

Comment: I am not sure about your configuration but if that server is not connected to your own network or in some way linked to your Active Directory then I don't think that Integrated Security could work. Instead if this database is  hosted somewhere and you have all the firewall rules setup correctly then you could add the username and password given to you by your hosting provider. For the connection details look at [ConnectionStrings.com](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/)

Comment: You should check out [Can we stop using AddWithValue() already?](http://blogs.msmvps.com/jcoehoorn/blog/2014/05/12/can-we-stop-using-addwithvalue-already/) and stop using `.AddWithValue()` - it can lead to unexpected and surprising results...

Comment: Uh oh, Data Source should have a space between Data and Source

Comment: @Steve, thank you, I will modify the code and get back later today to confirm if I managed to make it work

Answer (score 0):

Two things:

- `Initial Catalog` should be set to your database name, not a username. Since you have set `Integrated Security=true` there is no need to pass in a username or password in your connection string - it will use the user account that is running in the context of your app.
- The Data Source property should be `Data Source`

`Data Source=s59.hekko.net.pl; Initial Catalog= truex2_kuba; Integrated security=true`

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString = GetConnectionString();
static private string GetConnectionString()
{
    return "Data Source = s59.hekko.net.pl; Initial Catalog = truex2_kuba; Integrated security=true";
}

private void druk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string queryString = "INSERT INTO [dbo].[barcode] ([ColumnNameForClassinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForTreeinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForTypeinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForAmountinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForLengthinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForWidthinbarcodeTable],[ColumnNameForSquareinbarcodeTable]) VALUES (@class, @tree, @type, @amount, @length, @width, @square)";
    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(queryString, sqlConnection))
    {
        try
        {
            //This example assumes all the columns are varchar(500) in your database table design, you may
            //likewise modify these to SqlDbType.Float, SqlDbType.DateTime etc. based on your design

            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@class", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = klasa.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@tree", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = gatunek.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@type", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = rodzaj.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@amount", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = amount.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@length", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = length.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@width", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = width.Text;
            sqlCommand.Parameters.Add("@square", SqlDbType.VarChar, 500).Value = length.Text;

            sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            sqlConnection.Open();
            int i = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
            sqlConnection.Close();

            if (i != 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Successful Insert.", "Success", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("Error.", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.